# How to combine JSON responses

Tags: c#, xml, json

So I'm trying to get back multiple json responses, combine them all into one JSON string and pass that to a view. Then I can iterate through the single response and have access to all the responses.

So far, I can't get it to work. I thought the easiest way to do it would be to convert the JSON strings to xmlnodes, add the xmlnodes to a document, then convert the document back to a single json string.

Here's my code to do so.

```
string json1 = GetXmlData();
string json2 = GetRestfulData();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode root = doc.CreateElement("root");
XmlDocument string1 = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"str1\":" + json1 + "}", "str1");
XmlNode node1 = doc.ImportNode(string1.FirstChild, true);
XmlDocument string2 = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"str2\":" + json2 + "}", "str2");
XmlNode node2 = doc.ImportNode(string2.FirstChild, true);
doc.AppendChild(node1);
doc.AppendChild(node2);
string response = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
return response;
```

But so far everything I've tried has resulted in errors. Is there a better way to do this or to make the above work?

The above gives an error that "doc" already has a documentElement node when it attempts to add node2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i take a look at the [JSON format](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp), i would say you can simply use `String.Join` all your JSON objects and put square brackets around them.

```
var jsonObjects = new List<string>();
jsonObjects.Add("{ 'firstName':'John' , 'lastName':'Doe' }");
jsonObjects.Add("{ 'firstName':'Anna' , 'lastName':'Smith' }");
jsonObjects.Add("{ 'firstName':'Peter' , 'lastName':'Jones' }");

var jsonObjectsArray = "[" + String.Join(jsonObjects, ", ") + "]";
```

Comment: Cakewalk... I knew I was making it harder than it was. Thanks!